# why JPA/HIbernate in Spring hbm2ddl.auto create does update instead of destroying old data?

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, hbm2ddl

Like the title said, i have a project with `spring+hibernate` through `JPA` and in `my persistence.xml` `hbm2ddl.auto=create` only updates the database. Apparently a lot of people out there have the same issue. So  my issue right now is that i have an import.sql which loads the system users etc which are uniques. It's a little annoying cleaning the database manually before running the program. is there any workaround **to clear the data before recreating it**. thanks 
my persistence.xml and context.xml are shown below:

```
<!--persistence.xml-->
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="normal" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>


 <!--context.xml-->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${mysql.jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${mysql.jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${mysql.jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${mysql.jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="normal"/>

    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_prefix"></prop>
            <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix">_AUDITED</prop>                
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.driverClassName">${mysql.jdbc.driverClassName}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">${mysql.jdbc.url}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">${mysql.jdbc.username}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">${mysql.jdbc.password}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">${mysql.hibernate.connection.provider_class</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">${mysql.hibernate.c3p0.max_size}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">${mysql.hibernate.c3p0.min_size}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">${mysql.hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">${mysql.hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">${mysql.hibernate.c3p0.max_statements}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">${mysql.hibernate.c3p0.timeout}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
```

Comment: "Clear the data before recreating it" is highlighted to avoid the `hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop` suggestion, isn't it?

Comment: hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop seem to work as it creates all the db objects then drop them afterwards. What i really need is the opposite as i will be running a webapp with recent state of my models.

Comment: I see, which version of Hibernate are you using? Some recent versions were affected by a bug that would fit your case.

Comment: `hibernate.version:4.0.1.Final`  
`spring.version:3.1.0.RELEASE`  
`hibernate.java-persistence.version:2.0-cr-1`

Comment: I noticed you have audit tables. Does the `hbm2ddl.auto=create` work as it should if the tables are not audited?.